# React stacking array of images horizontally when trying to add animation and using .Map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, carousel

So I'm trying to add slide animation on the the images but it not working as intended, the slide animation is working but the images gets stacked over in line horizontally and rest of the slides are empty

`here's the code with slide animation which is causing the bug`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { IoArrowBackCircleSharp, IoArrowForwardCircleSharp } from 'react-icons/io5';
import { useSwipeable } from 'react-swipeable';

export default function Carousel() {
  const images = [
     // Images array
  ];

  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentIndex((currentIndex + 1) % images.length);
    }, 4000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [currentIndex, images.length]);

  const nextImage = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((currentIndex + 1) % images.length);
  };

  const previousImage = () => {
    setCurrentIndex(currentIndex === 0 ? images.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1);
  };

  const handlers = useSwipeable({
    onSwipedLeft: nextImage,
    onSwipedRight: previousImage,
    preventDefaultTouchmoveEvent: true,
    trackMouse: true,
  });

  const slideStyles = {
    transform: `translateX(-${currentIndex * 100}%)`,
    transition: 'transform 0.5s ease-in-out',
  };

  return (
    <div
      id='slideSection'
      className='max-w-fit m-auto pt-[6.80rem] sm:pt-28 relative group left-0 right-0'
      {...handlers}
    >
      <div className="carousel">
        <div className="slides" style={slideStyles}>
          {images.map((image, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="slide">
              <img
                className='image h-80 w-screen sm:h-128 object-cover'
                src={image.url}
                alt={`${index}`}
              />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
        <div className='hidden md:group-hover:block absolute sm:top-[55%] top-[62%] -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] rounded-full left-5 text-4xl sm:text-4xl md:text-6xl backdrop-blur bg-white-100/20 text-black cursor-pointer'>
          <IoArrowBackCircleSharp onClick={previousImage}></IoArrowBackCircleSharp>
        </div>
        <div className='hidden md:group-hover:block absolute sm:top-[55%] top-[62%] -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] rounded-full right-5 text-4xl sm:text-4xl md:text-6xl backdrop-blur bg-white-100/20 text-bisque-100 cursor-pointer'>
          <IoArrowForwardCircleSharp onClick={nextImage}></IoArrowForwardCircleSharp>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

`code that is working fine without the sliding animation`

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { IoArrowBackCircleSharp, IoArrowForwardCircleSharp } from 'react-icons/io5';
import { useSwipeable } from 'react-swipeable';

export default function Carousel() {
  const images = [
      // Images array
  ];

  const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      setCurrentIndex((currentIndex + 1) % images.length);
    }, 4000);
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, [currentIndex, images.length]);

  const nextImage = () => {
    setCurrentIndex((currentIndex + 1) % images.length);
  };

  const previousImage = () => {
    setCurrentIndex(currentIndex === 0 ? images.length - 1 : currentIndex - 1);
  };

  const handlers = useSwipeable({
    onSwipedLeft: nextImage,
    onSwipedRight: previousImage,
    preventDefaultTouchmoveEvent: true,
    trackMouse: true,
  });

  return (
    <div
      id='slideSection'
      className='max-w-fit m-auto pt-[6.80rem] sm:pt-28 relative group left-0 right-0'
      {...handlers}
    >
      <div className="carousel">   
              <img
                className='image h-80 w-screen sm:h-128 object-cover'
                src={images[currentIndex].url}
                alt={`${currentIndex}`}
              />
        </div>
        <div className='hidden md:group-hover:block absolute sm:top-[55%] top-[62%] -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] rounded-full left-5 text-4xl sm:text-4xl md:text-6xl backdrop-blur bg-white-100/20 text-black cursor-pointer'>
          <IoArrowBackCircleSharp onClick={previousImage}></IoArrowBackCircleSharp>
        </div>
        <div className='hidden md:group-hover:block absolute sm:top-[55%] top-[62%] -translate-x-0 translate-y-[-50%] rounded-full right-5 text-4xl sm:text-4xl md:text-6xl backdrop-blur bg-white-100/20 text-bisque-100 cursor-pointer'>
          <IoArrowForwardCircleSharp onClick={nextImage}></IoArrowForwardCircleSharp>
        </div>
      </div>
   
  );
}
```

I'm very new to programing, I just want add sliding animation to the working code

here's the link to codeSandbox for both above mentioned codes

[Working version with no animation](https://codesandbox.io/s/working-carousel-with-no-animation-g0vgcn?file=/src/App.js)

[Images stacking in line horizontally with animation working and rest of the slides empty](https://codesandbox.io/s/carousel-with-animation-bugged-yc3341?file=/src/Component/Carousel.js)